# jQuery/JS Output from array/loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, append

I have several links on a page, they are turned into an array with jQuery. Basically, when the user clicks "load more" on the page I would like to generate a `<ul>` with 4 images inside (or less if there aren't 4 remaining. I then need to shut the `</ul>`. I cannot figure out how I'd write this, does anyone know? Also, is this code ok or should it be tidied up somehow?

What I'd **really** like is a way to hide the 4 images while they load and then slide down the new `<ul>` but I don't know how as I don't know where I could write a callback function in there. Feel free to point me in the right direction if you know how!

My code so far;

```
var hrefs = jQuery.makeArray(jQuery('ul.js a'))

        jQuery('#load_more').bind('click',function(){

            jQuery('.img_gallery').append('<ul>')
            for(var c = 0; c < 4; c++){
                if((hrefs.length) > 0){
                jQuery('<li>').append(jQuery('<img>', {src:hrefs[0]})).appendTo(jQuery('.img_gallery'))
                hrefs.splice(0,1)
                }
            }
            jQuery('.img_gallery').append('<ul>')
        })
```

Thanks : )

Comment: You can substitute almost all that JQuery calls with the $ sign, that makes your code a lot clearer.

Comment: Yep I know, I starting writing other script without the dollar sign but I'll sort it all out once this is done (if I get it done!)

Comment: Please don't forget to add semicolons to the end of each complete line of code. It may not make any difference to the parser, but it makes your code much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach .. this is lot cleaner

```
var hrefs = jQuery.makeArray(jQuery('ul.js a'))

jQuery('#load_more').bind('click', function() {
    var html = '<ul>'
    for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        if ((hrefs.length) > 0) {
            html += '<li><img src="' + hrefs[0] + '" /></li>' ;
            hrefs.splice(0,1);
        }
    }
    html += '</ul>'        
    jQuery('.img_gallery').append(html )
})​
```

Comment: No, it does what I want as I use the first one and then splice it off the array each time. Well, that's how I got it to do what I needed..

Comment: That looks great, but I still need the splice? Basically it's got 50 items and I need to output 4 at a time until it's empty...

Comment: You can just remove the c and add the splice according to your requirement .. Edited the code  .. If you want to hide it on page load.. Just  write this  $('ul').hide()

Comment: Why are you using raw html, rather than creating elements with jQuery?

Comment: I think inserting elements all at once is faster compared to appending them in every iteration..

Answer (score 0):

When you use jQuery you are not appending html *tags*, you are appending html *elements*.

When you do `$('.img_gallery').append('<ul>')`, and then `$('.img_gallery').append('<li>')`, you end up with a structure like this:

```
<div class="img_gallery">
    <ul></ul>
    <li></li>
</div>
```

You do not have to worry about closing tags, just creating elements.  jQuery "closes" all the tags for you in a sense.  You need to append your `li` elements to the `ul`, not the `.img_gallery`.  Just append to the last `ul`:

```
var hrefs = $.makeArray(jQuery('ul.js a'))

$('#load_more').bind('click',function(){
    $('.img_gallery').append('<ul>');

    for(var c = 0; c < 4; c++){
        if((hrefs.length) > 0){
            $('<li>').append($('<img>', {
                src: $(hrefs[0]).attr('href'); // get the link reference from the element
            })).appendTo($('.img_gallery ul').last());  // append to the last ul, not .img_gallery
            hrefs.splice(0,1);
        }
    }
});
```

Or, you can keep your `ul` as a variable, add your `li`'s and append the list after the loop:

```
var hrefs = $.makeArray(jQuery('ul.js a'))

$('#load_more').bind('click',function(){
    var newul = $('<ul>');  // Makes an element, not a tag

    for(var c = 0; c < 4; c++){
        if((hrefs.length) > 0){
            $('<li>').append($('<img>', {
                src: $(hrefs[0]).attr('href'); // get the link reference from the element
            })).appendTo(newul);  // append to the ul you created
            hrefs.splice(0,1);
        }
    }

    $('.img_gallery').append(newul);
});
```

Comment: I didn't see he was closing tags, well spotted.

Comment: This is cool, I'm learning some good stuff here. I'm just looking at what's in my array now, because I think it holds the whole <a> tag not just the href it should. Also, this code produces empty <ul>'s when I'm out of items in the array, how could I stop that? Wrap an IF statement round it?

Comment: You can just do `if(hrefs.length == 0) { return false; }` at the beginning of your function.

Comment: And, yes, `makeArray` returns an array of DOM elements, not just the hrefs, which is why in my code I do `.attr('href')` to get the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your `hrefs` array contains DOM elements, not URLs. Try this instead:

```
var hrefs = jQuery.map(jQuery('ul.js a'), function(el,i) {
    return $(el).attr('href');
});
```

Incidentally, you can optimize your `for` loop as follows:

```
for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
    if (hrefs.length) {
        jQuery('<li>').append(jQuery('<img>', {
            src: hrefs.shift() // removes and returns the first array element
        })).appendTo(jQuery('.img_gallery'));
    };
};​
```

Comment: This is weird, how come it works when my array is full of links?! I wrote it wrong, is should have been `var hrefs = $.makeArray(jQuery('ul.js a').attr('href'))` shouldn't it?

Comment: `$.makeArray(jQuery('ul.js a').attr('href'))` will give you an array containing only one element, the `href` of the first link. You need to use `jQuery.map` to build the complete array.

Comment: Just use `.append()` and `.appendTo()` as needed. See [this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) for the other methods you may not have learned yet.